# Using with and withCount together in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, with-statement

withCount is a new method of laravel to return count of the relations. I'm trying to use with and withCount together. For example:

```
Article::with('Comments')->withCount('Comments')->paginate();
```

Problem I'm facing is, in the results is see for example:

```
comments_count = 10
comments = []
```

It returns comments array null. I don't know is it possible to get both the results or not. In some articles on different sites, i see withCount still has some restrictions. But not sure what I'm trying to do is possible or not.

Please help me to know about this issue.

Thank you,

Comment: yes. it is possible to get both results. and your code is fine to do that. can you show  the result of that query?

Comment: if I use only "WITH" it returns: comments:[{id:1, comments:"---"},{id:2, comments:"-----"}], if I use online withCount, it returns: comments_count:2.... and if I use both it returns: comments:[], comments_count:2

Answer (score 1):

No Need to write with.

```
Article::withCount('Comments')->paginate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately this didn't worked for me. I tried this but it returns only "comments_count" without comments. I need comments array too.

Comment: This will not load the relationship, OP's code is correct.